# VBA Word change text colour in shapes

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to change the font color in shapes via VBA. This does not work, and I don't understand where is the error.

Output: Runtime Error 5917, this object does not support the attached text.

```
Sub TextColorChange()
Dim s As Shape
For Each s In ActiveDocument.Shapes
  If s.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.TextColor.RGB = RGB(125, 125, 125) Then
     s.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.TextColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
  End If
Next
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, I am vba beginner. I dont understand - you think I need to set Dim s? Could you please give a hint?

Comment: What line throws the error?

Comment: I updated according to your proposal, @BigBen. The error comes from ```If s.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.TextColor.RGB = RGB(125, 125, 125)```

Comment: Try adding `If s.TextFrame.HasText` as an outer condition.

Comment: I have tried, no errors now but nothing changes

```Sub TextColorChange()
Dim s As Shape
For Each s In ActiveDocument.Shapes
    If s.TextFrame.HasText Then
        If s.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.TextColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0) Then
            s.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.TextColor.RGB = RGB(125, 125, 125)
        End If
    End If
Next
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Your first listing changes text in RGB(125, 125, 125) to RGB (0, 0, 0). You second listing does the opposite. If the real text color is different from the value in the If line, the code will do nothing.

Comment: @JohnKorchok yes I know, the color here is not relevant, I have both of these in my doc. The code runs but it produces no changes to the text in shapes, regardless the RGB colour. Its strange

Comment: Have you checked that it is actually an RGB colour and not a theme colour? Your code assumes that all the text in the shape is the same colour. Have you checked that it is?

Answer (score 0):

Use Font.Fill.ForeColor with RGB, as below:

```
s.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(125, 125, 125)
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you tried
TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(125, 125, 125)

Comment: You might find it wise to test your code before you post answers. Your suggestion won't compile.

Comment: Please avoid wrong suggestions. come up with a tried and tested answer

Answer (score -2):

It seems like word vba do not support to change font colour in shapes, so I did it manually

Comment: This is completely untrue. In order to change the text color by its RGB value you first need to know what the correct RGB value is. `s.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.TextColor.RGB` will only return 0 if the color was applied using the 'More Colors...' dialog. If the 'Font Color' palette shows the color as 'Automatic' it will have an RGB value of -16777216. If it shows that it is 'Text 1' then the RGB value will be -587137025. Dependent on the document's theme colors the text in all three cases will be black.

Comment: It does. Please see my answer above and accept if it works for you